# Sort paginated list by length and then alphabetically in RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of units by length and then alphabetically. If I sort alphabetically, I get a list of the form

```
Troop 1     
Troop 11    
Troop 111   
Troop 1111  
Troop 5     
Troop 55    
Troop 555   
Troop 7     
Troop 77    
Troop 777
```

Instead I would like

```
Troop 1
Troop 5 
Troop 7     
Troop 11    
Troop 55    
Troop 77    
Troop 111   
Troop 555   
Troop 777
Troop 1111
```

I was thinking that doing a simple sort based on name length and then name alphabetically would do the trick, but I can't get any sorting on length to work. I've tried a few variations of the form

```
def index
  @title = 'Units'
  @units = Unit.paginate(page: params[:page]).order(name: :asc).sort{|x, y| x.name.length <=> y.name.length}
end
```

To no avail. It now occurs to me that I might need to split on space and sort by the second value (i.e. the number grabbed), but I don't know how to do that either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's usually called "Natural sorting" in programming.

Thankfully, you don't need to do it in Ruby. SQL is capable enough:

```
@units = Unit.paginate(page: params[:page]).order("LENGTH(name) ASC, name ASC")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually I found something interesting you may be able to help. If I add 'Crew 123' to the list, it puts it between 'Troop 7' and 'Troop 11'. Would it be possible to split on space and sort alphabetically on the first item in the split array and numerically on the second item in the split array?

Comment: `.sort{|x, y| x=x.split(' ');y=y.split(' '); x[0] == y[0] ? x[1] <=> y[1] : x[0] <=> y[0] }` probably

Comment: Doing `@units = Unit.paginate(page: params[:page]).sort{|x, y| x=x.split(' ');y=y.split(' '); x[0] == y[0] ? x[1] <=> y[1] : x[0] <=> y[0] }` gives the error `undefined method 'split' for #<Unit:0x007f36484af9b8>`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: oh, sorry. It's `x.name.split` (and `y.name.split`)

Comment: I had to take the pagination out for this to work, but doing `@units = Unit.all.sort{|x, y| x=x.name.split(' ');y=y.name.split(' '); x[0] == y[0] ? x[1] <=> y[1] : x[0] <=> y[0] }` gives the an alphabetized list with the same number problem listed in the original problem.

Comment: then replace the `x[1] <=> x[1]` with `x[1].to_i <=> y[1].to_i` I guess :)

Comment: Viola! You're the best!